# getting value of element in json response

Tags: php

my json response i am getting

```
$str = '{"Refund_Order_Result":{"reason":"","refund_status":0}} ';
$refoutput = json_decode($str,true);

print $refoutput->Refund_Order_Result->refund_status;
```

i want to get value of **refund_status** unable to do that . any way to get values

Comment: When you don't get the output you want, reduce it to something simple. In your case see what happens when you print `$refoutput`. Check if it is an object or an array and move forward from that.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($refoutput);//see this is an array so use below code
echo $refoutput['Refund_Order_Result']['refund_status'];
```

or

```
$refoutput = json_decode($str);//remove true this wil return object
echo $refoutput->Refund_Order_Result->refund_status;
```

**Note** : When `TRUE`, returned `objects` will be converted into `associative arrays.`

You have used true so you are getting `array` not `object`

Answer (score 2):

```
$refoutput = json_decode($str,true);
```

the above variable will give an array, so u have to use code like given below...

```
$refoutput['Refund_Order_Result']['refund_status']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$refoutput['Refund_Order_Result']['refund_status'];
```

try this